# How can I reduce table scan time in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT
    key,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'electronics' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'tv' THEN first_dt_bought END) AS first_dt_bought_tv,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'electronics' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'tv' THEN first_dt END) AS first_dt_tv,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'electronics' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'tv' THEN amt END) AS first_amt_tv,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'fruit' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'apple' THEN first_dt_bought END) AS first_dt_bought_apple,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'fruit' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'apple' THEN first_dt END) AS first_dt_apple,
    MIN(CASE WHEN LOWER(product) = 'fruit' AND LOWER(sub_pr) = 'apple' THEN amt END) AS first_amt_apple
FROM contacts 
where (product IN('fruit','electronics')) OR (sub_pr IN('tv','apple'))
GROUP BY 1;
```

How can I rewrite this logic in a better way to reduce table scan time

Comment: Help me reproduce the use case - how many rows, how many columns, any way to generate sample data, how much scan time are you getting right now?

Comment: How long is it taking and on what warehouse size? I would start with `where ((product='fruit' and sub_pr='apple') or (product='electronics' and sub_pr='tv'))` and if that doesn't help, add more details about table size and execution plan

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information to solve the problem. If the table's clustering on the `product` column is good, then it may help to refactor the disjunction into a union. However, that will almost certainly do no good if the clustering is poor on the `product` column.